# CONCAT is not valid at this position

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create records of tier 2 with using the name of tier 1 records and appending 2 in their name. Like "Tools 2", I want to create records for other records (with tier = 1).

[image]

I am using this query in mysql -
`insert into dummy_1 (ca2_name, ca2_tier) VALUES (CONCAT(select ca2_name from dummy_1 where ca2_tier=1, " 2"), 2);`

But it is throwing error - "CONCAT" is not valid at this position, expecting a complete function. Not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a subquery as an expression, it has to be enclosed in parentheses, in addition to the parentheses that are used for wrapping the `CONCAT` arguments.

```
insert into dummy_1 (ca2_name, ca2_tier) 
VALUES (CONCAT((select ca2_name from dummy_1 where ca2_tier=1), " 2"), 2)
```

But a better way to write this is to use a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO dummy_1 (ca2_name, ca2_tier)
SELECT CONCAT(ca2_name, ' 2'), 2
FROM dummy_1
WHERE ca2_tier = 1
```